# unexpected "," but can't find it for the life of me

Tags: php, arrays, geo

I'm running a script to redirect users based on country code, and right now the response I get is

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home2/mcp/public_html/redirect/index.php on line 15`

This is line 15: `$country_codes = 'US', 'CA', 'UK', 'AU', 'NZ', 'ZA', 'NL';`

Used here:

`if (in_array($var_country_code, array($country_codes))) {`

When deleting line 15 and just adding it in where $country_codes sits right now, giving me:

`if (in_array($var_country_code, array('US', 'CA', 'UK', 'AU', 'NZ', 'ZA', 'NL'))) {`

it works fine.

Anyone that sees the error?
If you need more code please let me know :)

Thanks!

Using the GeoIP plugin btw.

Comment: What are you intending to do for line 15, setup an array of country codes?

Comment: yeah pretty much, it's more for user friendly-ness to do it this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make it an array.

```
$country_codes = array('US', 'CA', 'UK', 'AU', 'NZ', 'ZA', 'NL');
```

and then

```
if (in_array($var_country_code, $country_codes)) {
```

because it will be an array already.

Comment: any changes I need to make to: `if (in_array($var_country_code, array($country_codes))) {` ?

Comment: great, this worked like a charm and taught me what I was doing wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You try to assign an array like this:

```
$country_codes = 'US', 'CA', 'UK', 'AU', 'NZ', 'ZA', 'NL';
```

while you should do it like this:

```
$country_codes = array('US', 'CA', 'UK', 'AU', 'NZ', 'ZA', 'NL');
```

or like this:

```
$country_codes = ['US', 'CA', 'UK', 'AU', 'NZ', 'ZA', 'NL'];
```